# If $u_k$ converges uniformly on $\partial \Omega$, does it converge uniformly on $\Omega$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, maximum-principle

Let $u_k$ be continuous on $\overline \Omega$ and harmonic in $\Omega$. Suppose $u_k$ converges uniformly on $\partial \Omega$. Can we conclude that $u_k$ converges uniformly on $\Omega$?

Comment: You need some assumptions on $\Omega$. On a ball, [the Poisson's kernel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_kernel#On_the_ball) gives you a way to go.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro  In class, the teacher says by maximum principle. I don't know how it follows from the maximum principle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Careful: This is not true for any $\Omega.$ For example let $u_k(x,y) = (-1)^ky$ in the upper half plane $\Omega $ of $\mathbb {R}^2.$ Then all $u_k$ vanish on $\partial \Omega,$ hence converge uniformly there, but the $u_k$ converge nowhere in $\Omega.$

This will be true for all bounded $\Omega$ however. There it's just the maximum principle:

$$\sup_{\overline {\Omega}} |u_k-u_j|\le \sup_{ \partial \Omega}|u_k-u_j|.$$